# ROR + Execute CMD Prompt at Windows platform using RUBY

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, I want to run cmd prompt at windows platform using ruby code.  Means click at one of the url at webpage, it will run command prompt at windows hosting server with parameters.

Here I want to pass some rails command to execute like

> "rails generate model User first_name:string"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like risky business, but at the most basic Ruby level you can use `system`

```
system "rails generate model User first_name:string"
```

[Kernal:System Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Kernel%3asystem)